# How to post multiple images using multipart / formdata in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipartform-data

I am trying to post two images to an url using multipart post request in Objective C , From my code I can able to send only one image, How to send two images to the url, using multipart / form data I have tried so many example for this bur I did not get the result I want

```
-(void)processPostMultipartRequestNew{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

NSString *urlStr =  [self.dataModel.apiUrl 
stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
urlStr = [urlStr 
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
urlStr= [urlStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];



NSURL *reqUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:reqUrl];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];



NSDictionary *requestBody = self.dataModel.requestParams2;
UIImage *imageToUpload = [requestBody objectForKey:keyUploadImage];


NSDictionary *requestBody2 = self.dataModel.requestParams;

UIImage *imageToUpload2 = [requestBody2 objectForKey:keyUploadImage];
    if(requestBody){
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0);//no compression by default
    NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload2, 0);

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"uploadedfile1\"; filename=\".jpeg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"uploadedfile2\"; filename=\".jpeg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData2]];

    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];





    // Text parameter1
    NSString *param1 = @"111";
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"SyncId\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:param1] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
}

[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setHTTPMethod:REQUEST_TYPE_POST];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60*4];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {


     NSLog(@"completionHandler with response:%@",[NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]]);
     NSLog(@"reponse: %ld",(long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]);

     NSInteger status = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];

     if(error){
         NSLog(@"http request error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
         // handle the error
     }
     else{
         if (status == 201){
             // handle the success
         }
         else{
             NSLog(@"error");
         }   // handle the error
     }
     if(!data || data == nil)
         return ;
     NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

     NSDictionary *resultDict  =(NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization
                                                  JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                  error:&error];

     //NSDictionary *resultDict  =(NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

     self.dataModel.responseData =resultDict;
     NSLog(@"error is %@",error);
     NSLog(@"data is %@",data);

     {

     if(!data || data == nil)
         return ;
     NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
     //for failed case
     if(error || error != nil){
         self.dataModel.responseFailed = YES;
         self.dataModel.error = error;
         NSLog(@"Result in error case %@",[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSDebugDescription"]);
         [self.reciever performSelectorOnMainThread:self.callBack withObject:self.dataModel waitUntilDone:YES];
     }
     else{
         self.dataModel.responseFailed = NO;
         self.dataModel.error = nil;
         NSString  *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         if(!([response rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location==NSNotFound))
         {
             NSString *res=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             self.dataModel.responseData =res;
             [self.reciever performSelectorOnMainThread:self.callBack withObject:self.dataModel waitUntilDone:YES];
         }

     }
     }
     self.executing = NO;
     [self setFinishedState:YES];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

     [self.reciever performSelectorOnMainThread:self.callBack withObject:self.dataModel waitUntilDone:YES];

 }];
  }
```

Is this a right way to do? if not how can I get success in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried @Sh_Khan answer  and I am getting the error response as Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.} How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can like this
Edit
///////////////////////////////

```
      // Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.
NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:@"ios" forKey:@"device_type"];
[_params setObject:@"user" forKey:@"type"];
[_params setObject:"iddddd" forKey:@"user_id"];

// the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

// string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ


// the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http........"];

// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in [_params allKeys]) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add txt data
```

/////////////////////////////

```
 NSArray *allImagesData= @[UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUpload) ,UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUpload2)];

NSLog(@"files array before %@", allImagesData);

for (int i=0; i<[allImagesData count]; i++)
{ 
    NSString*filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpeg",i+1];

    NSString* FileParamConstant = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",i+1];

    NSData *imageData = allImagesData[i];      

    if (imageData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", FileParamConstant,filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


}
```

Comment: How to add my images to that filePathArray, U have not mentioned any where?

Comment: it's the path where my files were , you can change the path directly to your images

Comment: change it to 2 if you want to upload 2 images

Comment: I am getting the images as data then how to add this data to array

Comment: I tried this and I am getting the error response as  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.} How to fix this?

Comment: I added FileParamConstant in for loop only still no change in response

Comment: above edit works with me........ + old part to send txt files or images

Comment: Your code is working for me but my images are not going in order and rotating also do you have any idea how to overcome this

Comment: sure ordering according to sending protocol but for rotation you may try UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUpload) instead of UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0) , also mark right if it worked

Comment: thanks for your edit, but my backend server is accepting only jpeg. what to to for this

Answer (score 0):

U can do like this:

```
-(void)PostUrlCall_Multipart_Image:(NSString *)IN_URL Param:(NSDictionary*)IN_Param Image:(UIImage *)image
{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];

    [manager POST:IN_URL parameters:IN_Param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) name:@"image" fileName:@"image" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    }
    progress:nil
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        m_Status=1;
        self.dic_Response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:m_strPostMsg object:self];

    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error){
        m_Status=0;
        self.dic_Response=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
//        [self.dic_Response setValue:@[Time_Out_Msg] forKey:@"@[Time_Out_Msg]"];
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:m_strPostMsg object:self];
    }];
}
```